# I need to alter the formatting of 700 excel files using the format of one sheet

Tags: excel

So, I have 700 excel files which each need the format in one sheet changing.

I have a master sheet with the correct format which I have tried to copy and then paste special format. But this doesn't seem to work and when it pastes in the individual file it just goes grey.

```
wsCopyFrom.Range("A810:A01134").Copy
                wsCopyTo.Range("A1:AO325").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

This is the code that I have in the Macro

any help ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
Sheets("Master").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy

'Loop this part
Sheets("SheetA").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
'Loop up to here


Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Try it yourself, you simply need to find a way to loop through selecting all the sheets.